My Solana wallet is not connecting to my tapswap if I tap on go it does not take me anywhere and there is noting like start a mission why?
My solona wallet is not connecting to my tapswap. there is no start a mission while connecting the wallet and when you tap on go it will not take you anywhere I need help on this please
